# Making Sure All tasks executes in onLocationChanged Method

Tags: android, locationmanager, locationlistener

I am doing a lot of job in onLocationChanged method, i want to lock the method until all jobs are done even if the location manager achieves it's condition.

for example i have the following code:

```
private LocationManager _locMgr;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                _locMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            _locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 2, this);
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

//do alot of job

 }
```

The problem i am facing that if the time in locationManager is greater than 2 seconds and greater than 2 meters it'll execute the onLocationChanged() even if there's tasks not finished.

Please somebody help me with this.

Comment: just change the meters and second then?

Comment: @user2511882 I tried so, but i don't know the exact time it takes to execute all tasks in onLocationChanged(), so if i know the exact time i'll change the meters and seconds depending on that time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that onLocationChanged() is called before finished, try this:

Declare an Activity field `private bolean isAllDone = true;`
Declare a lock object `private final Object lock = new Object();`

Then at onLocationChange test it:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if(isAllDone){
        synchronized (lock){
            if(isAllDone){
                isAllDone = false;
                //do alot of job
                isAllDone = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you remaral, i didn't try it yet, but i have a question.. is this will insure all tasks to be done even if the method onLocationChanged() is called again ?

Comment: Alright I've read about synchronized and it's sure will done the job :)) Thanks a lot for your help appreciate it.